# Add borders to Header with BootStrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using trying to use Bootstrap to add black borders. My header is divided into three sections.

- The first section has 4 rows.
- The Middle section has one row in the center.
- The Third section is divided into two section.

Also can you show me an example of a blue fill row in the first section (make the background blue in any of the first section row is fine).

I would like to have border on section one, two and three (all around and in between lines.

Below is my code please help and it will be great if you can show me an example on jsfiddle.

```
<style>
    .container {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .PI1{
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
        box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
    }
</style> 

<!-- Border Outline -->

<header>
    <div class="Header" id="Header Information">
        <div class="content container">
            <div class="row">
                <article class="service col-md-4">
                    <div class="PersonalInformation">
                        <div class="PI1"><p> Sponsers:</p></div>
                        <div class="PI1"><p> Dept. and Resp:</p></div>
                        <div class="PI1"><p> Date:</p></div>
                        <div class="PI1"><p> Updated:</p></div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="service col-md-4">
                    <br>
                    <H2> Title:</H2>
                    <br>   
                </article>
                <article class="service col-md-2">
                    <p> Manager:</p>
                    <p> TM:</p>
                    <p> TM:</p>
                    <p> TM:</p>
                </article>
                <article class="service col-md-2">
                    <p> TL:</p>
                    <p> TM:</p>
                    <p> TM:</p>
                    <p> Coach:</p>
                </article>
            </div><!-- row -->
        </div><!-- content container -->
    </div><!-- Personal Information Heading -->
</header>
```

Comment: which tag u referring as 1st section?

Comment: @vasanth This tag -   <article class="service col-md-4">
    <div class="PersonalInformation">
    <div class="PI1"><p> Sponsers:</p></div>
    <div class="PI1"><p> Dept. and Resp:</p></div>
    <div class="PI1"><p> Date:</p></div>
    <div class="PI1"><p> Updated:</p></div>
    </div>
    </article>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per my assumption i had found solution via css

css

```
.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.PersonalInformation div.PI1:first-child{
    background:blue
}

.PI1{
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
}
article:nth-child(2){
     border-left:1px solid #111;   
    border-right:1px solid #111;  
}
```

if your requirement is not fulfill  can u send image of what u need